# Creating ListView from a List of class objects returns same object instead of all C# UWP

Tags: c#, list, class, listview, uwp

I am attempting to list the List's items but I get repeatedly displayed the first row of the List. The List should contain three different product rows. Instead, ListView shows the same, first row three times.

I create list like this:

```
        List<ProductsNumber> ProductsNumberList = new List<ProductsNumber>();
        ProductsNumber _ProductsNumber = new ProductsNumber();
        for (int i= 0; i <= otherlist.Count - 1; i++)

        {
            _ProductsNumber.ProdId = otherlist[i].ProdName.ToString();
            _ProductsNumber.ProductsNumber = (DB_ProductList.Where(Product => Product.ProdId == otherlist[i].ProdName)).Count();
            ProductsNumberList.Add(_ProductsNumber);
        }

        //listView
        listBox.ItemsSource = ProductsNumberList;//Binding data to LISTBOX
```

And here is the class used to populate List:

```
 public class ProductsNumber
    {
        public string ProdId { get; set; }
        public int ProductsNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

If you are interested:

```
otherlist
```

works just fine when I list it in listview.

DB_ProductList is defined like this:

```
ReadAllProductsList dbproduct = new ReadAllProductsList();
        DB_ProductList = dbdproduct.GetAllProducts();
        List<Product> ProductList = new List<Product>();
        ProductList = DB_ProductList.ToList();
```

and it works well too.
Anyway, I get correct ProductNumber in ListView. It's the ProdId that gives me problems. I get indeed correct number of iterations in ListView, but they all are the same. ListView should list all Products, and not repeat the same one.

Any clue?

I am guessing that when populating List the same record is inserted three times. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solved the mystery.
Simply, moved the

```
ProductsNumber _ProductsNumber = new ProductsNumber();
```

line inside the `for`
loop and it works fine now. 
Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try write "ProductsNumber _ProductsNumber = new ProductsNumber();" into the loop?